# Magic ASP.NET MVC Controller Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a single route in my route config, as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Bulletins", action = "IndexView"} );
```

These defaults point to a BulletinController class, which inherits from the following class (with type parameter :

```
public class BmaPagedController<T> : BmaController<T> where T : class, IEntityBase
{
    public override ActionResult IndexView ( DataFilter<T> filter = null, int pageIndex = 0, string sortField = "", bool descending = true )
    {
        try
        { ...
```

When I run the site for the first time, the IndexView method is being called with an actual DataFilter object value, instead of null, as I expected. From where does ASP.NET get this "magic" parameter value, since I have not passed it in anywhere? So far as I know, APS.NET MVC by itself does not do any dependency injection, does it?

Comment: The mechanism is called model binding which bind incoming parameters (form data, query string) to your action method parameters

Comment: Nothing is being 'injected'. The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes complex objects and then sets it property values based on route parameters, form values etc. (in you case there are none so any properties of `filter` would be there default values)

Comment: I think there is more to it. The DefaultModelBinder does not just create an object of action parameters unless a value for at least one property is provided. From your question it seems like you are not passing any value, just the url is requested, right?

Comment: @ Ibrahim ben Salah: Yes, this occurs when I have not passed any parameter

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah, The `DefaultModelBinder` **does** create an object

Comment: Is the model binder customizable? And can it work with a DI framework? I guess I can just go read the relevant docs, but any summary will be appreciated

Comment: Ah, I was confused by other scenario where param is annotated with [Bind(Prefix="model")]

Comment: You can create your own model binder. Why would you want it to _work with a DI framework_? What is it your trying to do? If you want `filter` to be `null` you can do `/Bulletins/IndexView?filter=`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Basically, I just want to ensure that `filter` is always of the correct type derived from DataFilter<T>.

Comment: I suspect you might be taking the wrong approach, but [this blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) should help with understanding the model binding process and how to create custom model binder  - see the section on _Abstract Model Binder_

Comment: Thanks, all. Wish I could select a response as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are missing object arguments of action methods automatically instantiated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219435/are-missing-object-arguments-of-action-methods-automatically-instantiated)