# Are missing object arguments of action methods automatically instantiated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider the following viewmodel, the view and the action method with no other action methods of the same name:

#### Viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel
{  
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

#### View

```
@model Project.Models.ViewModel
*@...@*
```

#### Action method

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(ViewModel vm) {
        return View(vm);
    }
```

How come, that when requesting the view without passing in a viewmodel, the request actually succeeds?
I'd expect the "Resource cannot be found error" and if the action method was actually found, I'd expect vm to be assigned to null, but when I checked, the viewmodel was actually instantiated.

I read up on the [execution process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612(v=vs.100).aspx) and about [routing](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx/), but I feel none the wiser. Is the instantiation carried out by the DefaultModelBinder or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: I believe MVC 1 indeed passed null and it was a constant nuisance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's carried out by DefaultModelBinder as you speculate. What do you want to achieve? Why does your architecture require a null argument? The HTTP protocol has no way to specify whether it should be null or instantiated. This distinction does not correspond to any protocol element. Therefore, MVC *must* pick one of them. Personally, I find the instantiation quite convenient. Models are supposed to be dumb DTOs.

Comment: I don't absolutely require it to be null. Quite simply, I was just curious and a quite a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that `DefaultModelBinder` does this. MVC 1 indeed passed `null` but that behavior has changed. There is no configuration option to change this.

The HTTP protocol has no way in its request data to specify whether a model should be null or instantiated. This distinction does not correspond to any protocol element. Therefore, MVC must pick one of the alternatives.